# customizable date time picker in ionic2

Tags: ionic2

[image]I  don't want to display date after selecting the date from date picker by using  tag is it possible following is the code
As is in the image i don't want to display the MAR 31,2017 is it possible??

```
    <ion-header>
      <ion-icon class="moreicon" name="more">
    <ion-datetime type="button" [(ngModel)]="myDate" (click)="get()"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-icon>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: which way do you need to show date then?

Comment: i don't want to show the date at all

Comment: why then you use date picker?

Comment: i want to filter the list data after user selecting the particular list

Comment: for that, a user needs to select the date from the picker or can you do that filter without showing the picker?

Comment: i want user to select date from picker when he presses on the menu button placed right side on header. then a picker should display and user selects a date then the list to be filtered according to the date but the date should not be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your component page where just do as shown below.

*.scss*

```
 .ios,
 .md,
 .wp
     {
      .datetime-text{
         display: none;
    }
}
```